# MySQL: comma-separated list of numbers of items

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a learning system based on students watching videos then answering questions attached to those videos. The (simplified) model is basically this:

Courses (a course definition, e.g. Basic Algebra)

```
----------------------------------------
| id   | int     | auto_increment | PK |
| name | varchar |                |    |
----------------------------------------
```

Course instances (an entry is logged in here when a user begins a course)

```
---------------------------------------------
| id        | int     | auto_increment | PK |
| course_id | int     |                | FK |
---------------------------------------------
```

Videos (associated with a given course)

```
---------------------------------------------
| id        | int     | auto_increment | PK |
| course_id | int     |                | FK |
| name      | varchar |                |    |
---------------------------------------------
```

Questions (associated with a given video)

```
--------------------------------------------
| id       | int     | auto_increment | PK |
| video_id | int     |                | FK |
| q_text   | varchar |                |    |
--------------------------------------------
```

**What I want** is to get all course instances and the number of questions per video, comma separated.

So for example, if a course had three videos attached to it, and the first video had two questions and the second and third video had one question each, I want this:

```
-----------------------------------
| course_instance_id | qs_per_vid |
-----------------------------------
| 1                  | 3,2,2      |
-----------------------------------
```

The best I've got from my own efforts is this:

```
SELECT
    ci.id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT videos.id) AS num_vids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(questions.video_id ORDER BY questions.video_id) AS questions
FROM course_instances ci
LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.course_id = ci.course_id
LEFT JOIN questions ON questions.video_id = videos.id
GROUP BY ci.id
```

That produces something like:

```
---------------------------------
| id | num_vids | questions     | <-- actually it's the vid ID of each question
---------------------------------
| 1  | 4        | 1,1,1,2,2,3,3 |
---------------------------------
```

...from which I can infer, by the repeated video ID sequences, that the first vid has three questions, and the second and third two.

But how can I end up with my desired output above?

Comment: You would make it a lot easier for anyone to help you if you posted an [mcve], which in your case would be all the necessary `create table` statements and a bunch of `insert into` statements that populate the tables with sample data, so that the query that gave you the best from your own efforts can be executed and yield the sample data you showed.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh - no; that would simply tell me the unique video IDs, no info on how many questions each video had.

Comment: @MikeNakis - my apologies; I had thought my info was pretty clear re: the model and what I'm working with. It didn't occur to post the actual create_table syntax etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate twice.  One method is before doing the `join`:

```
SELECT ci.id,
       COUNT(v.id) AS num_vids,
       GROUP_CONCAT(q.numquestions ORDER BY q.video_id) AS questions
FROM course_instances ci LEFT JOIN
     videos v
     ON v.course_id = ci.course_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT q.video_id, COUNT(*) as numquestions
      FROM questions q
      GROUP BY q.video_id
     ) q
     ON q.video_id = v.id
GROUP BY ci.id;
```

The subquery counts the number of questions for each video.  The outer query then concatenates these together into the result string that you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind explaining a little more about what's going on there so I can understand the approach?