# MySQL - reference outer table inside pseudo table on join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Forgive the phrasing of this question if it's a little off.

I have a scary SQL query, the following of which is a simplified excerpt.

It's for a video tuition website. The query pulls out course "instances" (when a user begins a course, it creates an instance of that course, tied to them) and, with it, a comma-separated list showing the number of questions on each video (the course is made up of a succession of videos with questions attached to it.)

So for example, if a course has 6 videos and the first 3 videos have 1 questione ach and the last 3 have 3 questions each, output would be:

```
------------------
| num_qs_per_vid |
------------------
| 1,1,1,3,3,3    |
------------------
```

Query excerpt:

```
SELECT
    ci.instance_id,
    ci.course_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(questions.num_qs, 0) ORDER BY videos.index) AS num_qs_per_vid,
FROM course_instances ci
LEFT JOIN videos ON ci.course_id IN (
    SELECT course_id_id
    FROM _taxonomy_assocs
    WHERE item_id = videos.id
)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT questions.id, questions.vid_id, unit, COUNT(*) as num_qs
    FROM questions
    WHERE unit = **problem** /* <-- need to reference outer ci.course_id */
    GROUP BY questions.vid_id
) questions ON questions.vid_id = videos.id && questions.unit = ci.course_id
WHERE ci.user = '{hard-coded user ID goes here}'
GROUP BY ci.id
```

Where I've put `*problem*` I need to reference the outer course instance ID. So ideally I'd do:

```
WHERE unit = ci.course_id
```

But this brings up an error saying ci.course_id is an unknown column. I presume this is a problem of chronology, i.e. the inner part running before the outer part, but I don't know how to resolve this.

If I specify a *specific* course instance ID, everything's fine.

```
WHERE unit = "abcdef123"
```

...it's just when I want to get several course instances.

(PS any typos/naming issues are the result of me simplifying the query for the purposes of this question; they're not in the actual query.)

Comment: What you're trying to do is a `LATERAL JOIN` which isn't currently in MySQL.  Before I look at the exact implementation of an alternative for you,  I assume this `, unit COUNT(*) as num_qs` is a typo?   In-fact, could you describe *exactly* what that sub-query does?  You're using a MySQL "feature" where by you can `GROUP BY` one field, but `SELECT` other fields without aggregating them *(`questions.id`)*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - at least I now know what it is I'm trying to achieve :) Yes - that was a typo during simplification; it's not in the actual query. Edited - thanks.

Comment: The query is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861133/mysql-comma-separated-list-of-numbers-of-items#answer-44861210), to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861133/mysql-comma-separated-list-of-numbers-of-items) I asked some months ago when trying to get this started. Essentially I just want the number of questions per video that's featured in the course.

Comment: But why do you `GROUP BY vid_id` and yet have `SELECT id, vid_id`?  Is there only one `id` per `vid_id`?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: As currently written it looks like it should behave fine without the `WHERE` clause.  You just need to `unit` to the `GROUP BY`, so that the sub-query gives one record per `vid_id, unit` combination.  As you're already including `unit` in the outer-query's `JOIN` predicate, that's all you need to do?

Comment: I can only shrug my shoulders - it's probably a bastardised version of a sound answer I received. It "sort of works", except for this problem. I'm open to suggestions. I'm not 100% confident in what the query does or whether it's all correct. I'll try your group by suggestion - when you say add it, you mean it should be `GROUP BY questions.vid_id, questions.unit)`?

Comment: Step 1.   `STOP` selecting fields that you're not grouping by.  Only MySQL supports this, and more recent versions have that functionality turned off by default.  Either include the field in the `GROUP BY` or make sure it's within an aggregating function *(`MAX()` or `SUM()`, etc)*

Comment: DUDE you've only just gone and nailed it. I had a suspicion all along that inner `where` was useless but couldn't crack it. I wouldn't have guessed at modifying the group-by. If you post this up as an answer I'll give you the rep.

Comment: Step 2. Make sure that your sub-query has `GROUP BY questions.vid_id, questions.unit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT questions.id, questions.vid_id, unit, COUNT(*) as num_qs
    FROM questions
    -- REMOVE THIS :
    -- WHERE unit = **problem** /* <-- need to reference outer ci.course_id */
    --               ADD THIS:
    GROUP BY questions.vid_id, questions.unit
) questions ON questions.vid_id = videos.id && questions.unit = ci.course_id
```

Also, including `questions.id` in the `SELECT` is a bad idea when it is not in your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Thanks for this - a big help. Could you please explain why it fixes it? I'm struggling to understand intuitively how you can group on multiple columns. If I group animals according to genus (cats vs. dogs) I can't, at the same time, group them by colour (brown vs. black), surely?

Comment: `LEFT JON (blah)` is just joining an another "table" / "data-set".  In this case the sub-query *(also known as an inline-view)* creates a table of `vid_id, unit, count(*)`.  Imagine it as a real table with those summary stats for the whole table.  The `JOIN` then just picks which `(vid_id, unit)` you want, takes that one row, and now you have the `COUNT()` for that combination...

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But how about re: multiple columns in the `GROUP BY`clause? Intuitively, how can you group something by two criteria at once?

Comment: I don't want to try to teach SQL in comments, but I will answer this last one.  `GROUP BY` describes a desire to "collapse" or "fold" many rows together.  If you group by `genus` then you want all `'cat'` records aggregated into a single record, and also all `'dog'` records aggregated in to a single record.  Each different value in `genus` yields a single output row, regardless of how many input rows there were.  If you `GROUP BY genus, sex` you will get one row for `dog, male`, one row for `dog, female`, one row for `cat, male`, one row for `cat, female`, etc, etc.

Comment: Wasn't after a teaching, just an explanation of the answer, which is presumably a reasonable use for SO comments. Thank you.